# play 2.0 templates html select with if statement in a map

Tags: templates, select, playframework-2.0

I want to create a `<select>` without using the helpers (because the select helper is generating a *lot* of html)

So, I get a list of cities from the Controller like:

```
public static List<City> getAllSortedByNameAsc() {
    List<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();
    cities.addAll(City.find.orderBy("name").findList());
    return cities;
}
```

In my template, I create the options with this code:

```
@cities.map { city =>
    <option value="@city.id">@city.name</option>
}
```

which works, but I also want to have the chosen city as selected value. I tried several things like this:

```
@cities.map { city =>
    <option value="@city.id" selected="@if(offerForm("city.id").value == city.id){selected}">@city.name</option>
}
```

But that doesn't work. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Take a look at the original helper, maybe it'll help you: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html

Comment: @cities.map { city =>
    <option value="@city.id" @if(offerForm("city.id").value == city.id) "selected" else "">@city.name</option>
}

Comment: 'at' jittakal: I'm sorry, doesn't work!
"illegal start of simple expression" -> http://i50.tinypic.com/2wbsqvk.png

and @nico_ekito: the solution that the use in your link doesn't work too, but without a compilation error. I wrote: "@(if(offerForm("city.id").value == city.id)"selected" else "testELSE")"
So, this is exactly the code from the link, but in all three options (in my example) there is done the else-part. 
But the offerForm("city.id").value is correct (in my example 2) and the city.id are 1,2 and 3 :-\ damn it. any further suggestions? thanks so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Configuration File: application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
ebean.default="models.*"
```

**Controller Class => Application.java**

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import models.City;
import play.data.Form;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

  final static Form<City> cityForm = form(City.class);

  public static Result index() {
    City pune=new City();
    pune.name="pune";
    pune.save();

    City mumbai=new City();
    mumbai.name="mumbai";
    mumbai.save();

    City city=City.get(2L);

    return ok(index.render(cityForm.fill(city),City.all()));
  }

}
```

**Model Class => City.java:**

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import java.util.List;
import com.avaje.ebean.validation.NotNull;

@Entity
public class City extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @NotNull
    public String name;

    public static Finder<Long, City> find = new Finder(Long.class, City.class);

    public static City get(Long id){
        return find.byId(id);
    }

    public static List<City> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

}
```

**Template File => index.scala.html**

```
@(cityForm: Form[City],cities: List[City])

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <select>
                @for(city <- cities){
                    <option value="@city.id" @{if(city.id.toString().equals(cityForm("id").value)) "selected='selected'"}/>@city.name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jittakal: oh man thanks for your work! That's amazing! It works!
So I recap, that we need this "toString()" that was the problem!
You did it with a @for-loop, but I tried again the "map-loop" and it works as well.

great! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about how the type mapping is working, but I would try

```
@cities.map { city =>
    <option value="@city.id" selected="@if(offerForm("city.id").value.equals(city.id)){selected}">@city.name</option>
}
```

rather than using the `==` operator.

You should also consider whether the helper has a good reason for generating all that HTML. It's generally a pretty smart framework.

Comment: no way, unfortunately! Either your soltion nor "<option value="@city.id" @(if(city.id.equals( offerForm("city.id").value) )"selected" else "test")>" -> always comes "test"-output so it's the else-part :-\ but there are the right ID's - so the if-condition must match... think it's only a syntax-problem.

yeah it's absolutley a pretty framework, but i don't want the html-output which the helper produces, so... I must help myself, but don't know how :-( but thanks anyway